# RTSP Streaming on Nokia N97 mini

Tags: video, streaming, symbian, nokia, rtsp

Can anone tell me if the Nokia N97 mini is capable of playing the following video stream via RTSP?

Container: 3gp
Video: h264
Audio: AAC Stereo 44KHz

I'm trying to start this stream via a HTML link that points to the RTSP-URL but when I tap the link, the fullscreen player comes up, tries to buffer the video and then stops with an error saying that it can't play the stream.

Answer (score 0):

RTSP is well supported on n97 (both mini and standard).

Realtime streaming in a given country is supported only if the service provider in that country supports it.

What is the error number that it throws? And the exact error message?